# Security benefits of Single Sign-On

Tags: authentication, sso

What are the benefits of a single sign-on implementation from the point of view of security?

**From my point of view**, if the account is compromised the attacker has access to any resource, so according to this, SSO is far from secure.

Comment: SSO, per se, isn't deployed to improve security. It's mainly used for convince. In _most_ installations, SSO is used as compromise of the security policy for the benefit of usability. It's all about finding your sweet spot on [the magical triangle](http://i.imgur.com/LhbIz9m.png).

Answer (score 2):

I can see three main benefits.

1. **Reduce the amount of passwords users have to remember.** Users are encouraged to use vastly different passwords for different sites. Managing that many different passwords can be problematic. Obviously this isn't an issue if the user uses a password manager tool but let's be realistic, how many users can you expect to do that? A SSO solution can greatly reduce the number of passwords a user has to remember, which might encourage the user to choose a much stronger password.
2. **Provides convenience to the users.** A SSO solution literally means the user has to sign on just one single time to access multiple services. This is a huge timesaver especially if a company provides multiple services. A good example of this would be Google. While this might not strictly be accurate, I have a feeling that by reducing the number of times a user has to enter his credentials, the risk of an attacker intercepting the credentials through something like a keylogger will be reduced.
3. **Reduce the headache of assisting users with password recovery.** Imagine a company running ten different services. A SSO solution can greatly reduce the amount of helpdesk manpower needed as users only need to recover a single account. Whilst not a security concern, this is a very tangible benefit to companies.

Of course, a SSO solution concentrates a lot of power on the authentication solution. One should probably spend a lot more time and effort securing that single point of failure.

Comment: You are absolutely correct but these are usability benefits and not security benefits :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the words of [Shwetha on the Cymfony System Testing blog](http://cnpltesters.blogspot.fr/2011/06/single-sign-on-by-shwetha.html), Some of the common advantages are :

> 1. Users select stronger passwords, since the need for multiple
>      passwords and change synchronization is avoided.
> 2. Inactivity timeout and attempt thresholds are applied uniformly
>      closer to user points of entry.
> 3. It improves the effectiveness/timeliness of disabling all
>      network/computer accounts for terminated users.
> 4. It improves an administrator's ability to manage users and user
>      configurations to all associated systems.
> 5. It reduces administrative overhead in resetting forgotten passwords
>      over multiple platforms and applications.
> 6. It provides users with the convenience of having to remember only a
>      single set of credentials.
> 7. This also improves security as users find
>      it easier to remember their credentials and do not have to write
>      them down, allowing for a more efficient user log on process.
> 8. It reduces the time taken by users to log into multiple applications
>      and platforms